# Intent.getAction results in NULL

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I was trying to implement the sample code for the NFC viewer from android developers, but I'm not recieving any action from my intent, here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tag_viewer);
    mTagContent = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);

    final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();  
    final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction(); 

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {  
         onNewIntent(getIntent());
   }  
   else {  
       //nothing
   }

   // resolveIntent(getIntent());

}

void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Parse the intent
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(action)) {
        // When a tag is discovered we send it to the service to be save. We
        // include a PendingIntent for the service to call back onto. This
        // will cause this activity to be restarted with onNewIntent(). At
        // that time we ryead it from the database and view it.
        Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);
        NdefMessage[] msgs;
        if (rawMsgs != null) {
            msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
                msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
            }
        } else {
            // Unknown tag type
            byte[] empty = new byte[] {};
            NdefRecord record = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_UNKNOWN, empty, empty, empty);
            NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] {record});
            msgs = new NdefMessage[] {msg};
        }
        // Setup the views
      //  setTitle(R.string.);
        buildTagViews(msgs);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unknown intent " + intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
}
@Override
public void onNewIntent(final Intent newIntent) {
    super.onNewIntent(newIntent);
    final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();
    setIntent(queryIntent);
    resolveIntent(queryIntent);
}
```

And the intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name="TagReader_BuiltIn" 
         android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

the intent.getAction(); Always results in NUll, any ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: the code `onNewIntent(getIntent());` the `getIntent` will return the activity's intent who call your activity, so you need check who start your activity, it has action or not?

Comment: Under what circumstances are you expecting the `Intent`? Is the app started by tapping an NFC tag? Or is the app already running (in the foreground) and are you then tapping an NFC tag?

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem :/ any leads?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have android:launchMode="singleTop" in your activity manifast.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        final Intent queryIntent = getIntent();  
        final String queryAction = queryIntent.getAction();  
        if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(queryAction)) {  
             //do something
        }  
        else {  
            //do something
        }  
    }
    void resolveIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Parse the intent
    final String action= intent.getAction();

    .......
}

 @Override  
    public void onNewIntent(final Intent newIntent) {  
        super.onNewIntent(newIntent);  
        final Intent queryIntent = getIntent(); 
        setIntent(queryIntent);
        resolveIntent(queryIntent);
    }
```

instead of

```
String action = intent.getAction();
   @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    resolveIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: code updated. I have no idea why he's not catching the action

Comment: make sure you have android:launchMode="singleTop" in your activity manifast

Comment: edited the code, still action = null. Although I have other NFC reader apps on my phone, when i scan a tag, a popup windows comes up asking which application i want to use with the NFC..

Answer (score 0):

First check is NFC feature is available in your device or not.

Did you used the below permissions in your manifest file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
```

use `<action android:name="android.nfc.action.NFC_DISCOVERED"/>` instead of using

```
<action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>
```

and dont call onNewIntent() method manually. call method resolveIntent(Intent intent) in onResume like this

```
        super.onResume();      
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) 
        {
          resolveIntent(getIntent());
         }
```

Hope this helpfull..

Comment: still got action == null. I'm quite desperate by now ;p

Answer (score 0):

If your NFC chip got tag you should run the following check:

```
if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.equals(getIntent().getAction())) {
// Do something
}
```